# Internal links no longer working. Getting MAMP virtual host info instead

Tags: 7

My local site is running Drupal 7.43 using MAMP on Mac OS X 10.10.5. The site was running fine until recently, when all of the links on the front page were no longer working correctly. Each link now opens the same page. Here is a screenshot of that page.

> [image: MAMP message]

After much digging, I found out that turning off clean URLs allows me to access the rest of the site, which is a CiviCRM installation. I downloaded the files and database from a live site to verify the backup worked. It does work, but only if clean URLs are disabled. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since turning off Clean URLs seems to at least be a work around for your issue, it sounds that you have not correctly configured Clean URLs. To correctly enable/configure Clean URLs, refer to [Configure Clean URLs](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) in the installation guide.

If you're not familiar with Clean URLs yet, I suggest to review that documentation (for the version of Drupal that you're using) and make sure your server is correctly configured before proceeding.

Here is a summary of common steps/issues:

- With Apache HTTPD as web-server, you have to enable `mod_rewrite` and configure the necessary rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file.
- Usually, theses rules are applied automatically, when `mod_rewrite` is enabled. But in some cases, the `AllowOverride` directive is too restrictive to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out the line "RewriteBase /" in the .htaccess file, clean urls worked as expected and I no longer have a problem with the internal links.